# why it is not working with nodemon index.js while it is working with node index.js

Tags: express, backend, nodemon

nodmon : The term 'nodmon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nodmon index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodmon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

app listening on port

Comment: Could it be you mean `nodemon index.js` instead of `nodmon index.js`? See [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package//nodemon) package.